# AttributeError: module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'home'

Tags: python, django, email

Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию по почте на Django, 2 дня прошли безуспешно,  делаю по этому гайду

https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef

появилась такая ошибка

```
File "/Users/work/Projects/blog/myblog/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
AttributeError: module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'home'
```

инспектор ругается точно также и на **'signup'**, и на **'activate'** в

**myblog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from accounts import views

from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDeleteView,
    BlogCommentView,

)

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', BlogCommentView.as_view(), name='post_comment'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),

    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate, name='activate'),

]
```

**myblog/views.py**

```
import json
from urllib import request

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm


from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'post_comment.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    #fields = '__all__'

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Инспектор PyCharm'a говорит, что нужно создать функции: 'home', 'signup', 'activate' в **accounts/views.py**, я новичок в Django и поэтому извиняюсь заранее, если не совсем понятно построил вопрос, ибо я сам больше половины не понимаю. Буду благодарен любой помощи, спасибо

Comment: Смотрите, структура вашего проекта такая `app/ -> [myblog/ -> [urls, views (0)],  accounts/ -> [views (1)]]`. В `0` у вас лежат почти все вьюхи, втч `'home, signup, activate'`, а используете вы их как `from accounts import views; views.home`, то есть, из (1). Либо перенесите эти три дефки `(0) -> (1)`, либо импоритуйте их в `from .views import (home, signup, ...` и используйте `views.signup -> signup`.

Comment: Также, не  в обиду, а просто для общего образования, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: Когда я переношу из (0) -> (1), мне соответственно нужно перенести и все импорты из (0) -> (1), но в таком случае половина импортов не работает, а насчет "импортируйте их в `from .views import (home, signup, ...`" я не совсем понял, можно ваш телеграмм? Или напишите мне пожалуйста @Pppperfect